# Binding to child component's property in Angular version 8.1.2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a parent component, **home**, which has a child component, **delete-item**. I am trying to pass a string from the parent component (home) to the child component (delete-item).

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Including the delete-item component
import { DeleteItemComponent } from './components/delete-item/delete-item.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DeleteItemComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from '../items.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  private items: Array<string>;
  private itemToAdd: string;

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [];

    this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(
      (result) => {
        this.items = result;
      }, (err) => {
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

home.page.html

```
<div *ngFor='let i of items'>
    {{i}}<app-delete-item [item]="i"></app-delete-item>
</div>
```

delete-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from 'src/app/items.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-item',
  templateUrl: './delete-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-item.component.scss'],
})
export class DeleteItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: string;

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  /**
   * Calls for the item to be deleted once clicked.
   */
  private clickDeleteItem(): void {
      this.itemsService.deleteItem(this.item);
  }
}
```

delete-item.component.html

```
<button (click)='clickDeleteItem()'>Delete</button>
```

I get the following error when I navigate to the home page:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'app-delete-item'.
```

The delete-item component has an attribute 'item', because I used the *@Input() item* annotation to specify it. This makes me believe that the home component does not have access to the delete-item component as part of its module, but why would that be since it is listed in the app module?

Comment: It's listed in the app module, which makes it available to other components of the app module. But the home component is not part of the app module. It's part of the HomePageModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JB mentioned in the comment, those parent and child components are in two different modules, you need to have them on the same module to get rid of this error.

Either move **`HomePage`** component to **`AppModule`** or either way. Or use a shared module and export delete component.

Comment: After moving the HomePage component to the AppModule, both of the components were now in the same module and had access to one another. Great catch, and thanks for your help!